# Run verilog on Mac

Tags: macos

I need to simulate verilog on my Macbook Pro for school. I've tried downloading, configuring, and installing icarus and veriwell. The `make test` works for icarus, but not for veriwell, neither of them are recognized by the terminal.

The command I'm using is:

```
iverilog hello.vl
```

and

```
veriwell hello.vl
```

Terminal claims that neither of these commands exist...

I'm very new at configuring tools with the terminal, but I think the issue is just USING the program afterwards. Any ideas?

Comment: Does iverilog exist and are you trying to execute it from that path?

Comment: Not sure why this was moved from stackoverflow, there are other stackoverflow questions relating to setting up tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried veriwell but I use Icarus and [GTKWave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/) for a verilog simulation environment.

I use the verilog mode in [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) as a syntax highlighting editor.

Take your hello.vl (using just .v is more usual) and compile it using

```
iverilog -o hello hello.vl
```

This will create an object file called hello. To execute it, type

```
vpp hello
```

Once you start writing test benches, you will want to dump out a wave file. You do that by adding this to your test bench.

```
initial
 begin
  $dumpfile("wave.lxt");
  $dumpvars(0, <test bench module>);
 end
```

You can then load the wave.lxt into GTKWave (note that you need X11 to use GTKWave).

A little more advanced, you can set up Aquamacs to use Icarus to compile your code, so that you know if you have a compile error before leaving the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a `make install`? Assuming so, make sure that the directory it installed to is in your `$PATH`. If you are running csh/tcsh, you may need to run the `rehash` command for the shell to find new programs in the path.

Here are two similar questions:

- [-bash: ls: command not found at Terminal on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/233712/bash-ls-command-not-found-at-terminal-on-mac-os)
- [How to solve "command not found" on Ubuntu bash shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/134523/how-to-solve-command-not-found-on-ubuntu-bash-shell)